# What method does SpringJDBC uses to get latest key

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Following YSQL documentation: [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html) on the last paragraph it is mentioned that:

> ...that at times, it can be tricky to use the SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() query, as that function's value is scoped to a connection. So, if some other query happens on the same connection, the value will be overwritten. On the other hand, the getGeneratedKeys() method is scoped by the Statement instance, so it can be used even if other queries happen on the same connection, but not on the same Statement instance.

As I working in a completely distributed environment it is very important to me not to happen to get the wrong key back from the database...

Which of these methods is being used by springJDBC

I am using spring version `3.2.1.RELEASE` but i don't mined upgrading to the latest.

Comment: You can always look at the source code. But I would assume that it's using `getGeneratedkeys()` because `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` is MySQL specific and SpringJDBC has not DBMS abstraction layer other than JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Well. As suggested, i dug through the code untill i reached this little line.

```
ResultSet keys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
```

which is called from inside a `PreparedStatementCallback` anonymous class.

So for all intent and purposes the function:
`int org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource, KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder) throws DataAccessException`

this is a thread/process safe action